# Problem starting p4d on AWS, Perforce server warning: serverID is not set, what to do?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, perforce

[image]

I have a problem starting p4d on aws, when I run ./p4d this error comes out. It looks like it is not configuring the IP?

I have no idea what to do. I already configured port 1666 on AWS

[image: P4Admin][image: AWS]

Comment: Try adding ":1666" to the end of that server listing

Comment: Yeah, looks like the output from starting the server is just a warning and it's running. As @tkosinski pointed out, you need to add the port to the server address.